# Secure Electronic Transaction (SET Protocol)

Tags: encryption

I've looked into the SET protocol and some of the information are outdated. Therefore, I would like to ask if the SET protocol uses 3DES or AES or just the DES and the RSA?

Comment: Where have you looked? How have you decided that the information is out-of-date? Have you read the specs?

Answer (score -1):

That seems like a question that can be answered by looking at the specification of the SET protocol. The Wikipedia page for SET:

[en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Electronic_Transaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Electronic_Transaction)

lists several official-looking documents at the bottom under "[References](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Electronic_Transaction#References)". You can probably find your answer in there.